# How to save data from the view in Symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, view, doctrine-orm

How can I save datas in my DB from a view in Symfony2.

If I have a entity user and I use:

```
 $user->setInformation("Test");
```

That information doesn't stored in the DB.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should persist and do flush to save the changes in the database. Assuming you are using Doctrine ORM, the below code must work.

```
$user->setInformation("Test");
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I obtain this error: call to undefined method Symfony/.../getDoctrine()

Comment: Remember, I'm using this from a view, not from a controller

Comment: You should not do such logics in view

Answer (score 1):

View shouldn't contain entity persistence/save logic. You should use view only to represent data you get from controller.

$this->getDoctrine is alias to get default entity manager from DI container

So

- You should check which doctrine entity manager you use
- Ensure you can access dependency injection container. In controller you can use $this->get() or $this->getDoctrine() as container is alredy there
- Set fields
- If you create new entity you should persist it with $em->persist()
- Flush changes to database with $em->flush();